# Does MongoDB C# drivers support declarative operations?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to have some schema definition that will allow me to define e.g. all of the indexes that should be present. I can write `CreateIndex`, but it e.g. will not be deleted if I remove this line in code.

Is there some magic declarative coding in the MongoDB drivers that would allow for this? I.e. that when the synchronization would run the result is that schema/indexes in mongodb is the same as in code?

Comment: nope as far as I know